# Silent home web server and backup device

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, nas

I am looking for a piece of hardware that would be able to run Linux and act as a web, subversion and file server. Ideally it shouldn't have any fans, because it will be in the middle of my living room, the computing power needs are minimal. I would be grateful for recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of products based on the design of the [SheevaPlug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SheevaPlug) that only need storage connected in order to be full-fledged servers.

Comment: Certainly looks interesting, cheers! I am wandering if someone will come up with a solution with internal HDD.

Comment: The problem with having an internal hard drive is that you then are required to add cooling to the package since you don't know what sort of hard drive the consumer will add to the device.

Answer (score 0):

The reference on quiet or silent computers is [Silent PC Review](http://www.silentpcreview.com/). They have recommendations on [complete systems](http://www.silentpcreview.com/section7.html) (which include HTPCs and nettops) as well as parts.

You can also start with a network node such as the [SheevaPlug mentioned by Ignacio](https://superuser.com/questions/185627/silent-home-web-server-and-backup-device/185632#185632) and add some storage.

The most silent option is an SSD, but it will be expensive unless your storage needs are very modest. A hard disk will be the noisiest component of your system, even if it includes a (good) fan. If you go with a hard disk, check out [storage recommendations on SPCR](http://www.silentpcreview.com/section13.html) and get an enclosure they recommend (hard disk enclosure discussions tend to be in the forum).